# LEFT JOIN in QlikView not giving the wanted output

Tags: qlikview

I have one table:

```
Sessions:
Load 
    Timestamp,
    ...
    [Authenticated user]
FROM bla-bla
```

I want to joins that table with the data from one QVD file.
In the end effect, the table session should contain its fields as well as some fields from the second table.

So I did this:

```
LEFT JOIN (Sessions)
LOAD
      'DOMAIN\' & NT_USER & [Authenticated user],
      ...
      [Full_Name]
FROM
bla-bla-bla
```

[Authenticated user] field in the FIRST table has values with this format: 'DOMAIN\abc123'
Furthermore, NT_USER has the following values: 'abc123'

The join is not working. I can´t see the data from the second table. Any advice?

Comment: You should still be able to view the table in the Table Viewer (Ctrl + T) and then right click on the table in question and hit `Preview`.  You should be able to get some info from there to help with the merge issue you're having.

Comment: @bdiamante: I can`t see how previewing the data would help me in joining the tables. Can you please give more precise description? 
Furthermore, here is how the preview looks like: http://de.tinypic.com/r/2086xxk/5  the left join should be made between [Authenticated user] fields in both tables, and the field "Full Name" should be added to the first table (without keeping second table)

Comment: cab trimming maybe help? 
Are joining fields compatible the way I made them?
Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: I tried Trimming - doesn`t work

Comment: I interepreted `I can´t see the data from the second table` as you not being able to view the second table because of the qvd or something. Sorry about that -- as far as the join goes, I think you may want `'DOMAIN\' & NT_USER as [Authenticated user]` in your second table as your join key.  The way you have it now, you'd end with values like 'DOMAIN\abc123-whateverisinAuthenticatedUser-'.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I think it is best I send you the whole script: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6918259  this is the script that does not show the data (fields) fromm the second table

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem with uppercaseing the joining fields :)